# PHP Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established

Tags: php, wordpress

I installed Hybrid plugin on my Wordpress page and on activate this plugin I am getting this error:

```
PHP Warning: mysql_query(): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in /www/wp-content/plugins/hybridconnect/tableInstall.php on line 2056
```

So I checked this file (tableInstall.php) and there is function:

```
function check_column_exists($db, $column) {
    $exists = false;
    if ($columns = mysql_query("show columns from $db")) {
        while ($c = mysql_fetch_assoc($columns)) {
            if ($c['Field'] == $column) {
                $exists = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo (mysql_error());
    }
    return($exists);
}
```

So this line will cause error:

```
$columns = mysql_query("show columns from $db")
```

And from:

```
echo (mysql_error());
```

I am getting this:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
```

So this was worked on my old server and after I moved my site to another server I am getting this error.

What does this mean and how I can fix it?

Comment: Try using `mysqli` objects and functions... mysql is depreciated http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php

Comment: if you installed a plugin that uses `mysql_*` then what you need to do is uninstall it

Comment: Another server might not have mysql server on the same machine or uses different path to sock file, or uses tcp connection. ps: and where is your `mysql_connect` function? do not rely on default php settings.

Comment: There is not mysql_connect function. This plugin doesn't use it at all.

Comment: it most likely does use mysql_connect, is there a config file you need to edit or a form to fill in with database details? What you are seeing is a linux sql connect issue rather than code issue.

Comment: No this plugin doesn't use mysql_connect I searched all code, and there is not any conf file to fill or something. It worked fine on my old server and on a cople other sites which I teste works fine, just on this server I am getting this error.

Comment: You're getting this error on this server because mysql_* is not accepted. The plugin uses mysql_*, it's showing on your error - tableInstall.php on line 2056